# Regex to match multiple words contained within HTML span tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm working on a regex to match phrases in a HTML string.  For example, I want to find every instance of "artificial intelligence" and return the `<span>` tag that immediately precedes it.

The trouble I have is that the my regex only returns one large match.

Here is a link to an online regex builder I've been using: https://regex101.com/r/rK9yO9/1

I am looking to return the following two matches:

```
<span m='3'>
<span m='13'>
```

Example string:

```
<p><span m='2'>of</span> <span m='3'>artificial</span> 
<span m='4'>intelligence.</span><span m='4'>So</span> 
<span m='5'>that</span> <span m='6'>seems</span> 
<span m='9'>good.</span> <span m='10'>The</span> 
<span m='11'>impact</span> <span m='12'>of</span> 
<span m='13'>artificial</span> <span m='14'>intelligence,</span> 
<span m='15'>on</span> </p>
```

N.b there are no newlines in the text, I added those for readability.

The regex I have so far is:

`(<span.*>)artificial.?<\/span>.?<span.*>intelligence.?<\/span>`

Which returns the following match:

```
<span m='2'>of</span> <span m='3'>artificial</span> 
<span m='4'>intelligence.</span><span m='4'>So</span> 
<span m='5'>that</span> <span m='6'>seems</span> 
<span m='9'>good.</span> <span m='10'>The</span> 
<span m='11'>impact</span> <span m='12'>of</span> 
<span m='13'>artificial</span> <span m='14'>intelligence,</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  No explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
 /(<span[^<]+?>(?:artificial|intelligenc\.)<\/span>)/gm
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rK9yO9/4)

It should match only selected tags

Comment: You are an absolute legend!

Answer (score 2):

You are using greedy regex. To make matching stop at first occurrence use ?

```
(<span.*?>)artificial.?<\/span>.?<span.*?>intelligence.?<\/span>
```

will match

```
'<span m='2'>of</span> <span m='3'>artificial</span> <span m='4'>intelligence.</span>'
```

you can easily get the first group matched

Comment: Thank you, that helps.  It only matches the first instance, though. Any idea how to make it match every instance?  N.b. there are two instances of Artificial Intelligence in the string.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I think salems answer will match "artificial" which is not followed by "intelligence" also.  https://regex101.com/r/fZ4fY9/1

Comment: Ah interesting, hadn't thought of that.  I'm using Javascript but think I might need to find a different way around this particular problem.